# Summation using for loop and do while loop(java)

Tags: java, for-loop, sum, do-while, series

Confused on how to write a program using a for loop and a separate program using a do while loop in java that will sum the following finite series:

1/3+3/5+5/7+7/9+9/11... 95/97+97/99.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: why would you use two loops for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
double sum=0.0d;
for (int i = 1;i <= 97; i += 2) {
    sum += (double)i/(i+2);
}
```

Using the above, try to figure out the do-while loop

Answer (score 0):

The for loop should look something like

```
long sum = 0L;
for (int i = 1; i < 98; i = i + 2) {
    // i will be [1,3,5,...97]
    // Express the fractions in terms of i and add them to the sum
}
```

The while loop it would simply be moving the declaration of the induction variable to before the while loop, the terminating expression remains the same, and incrementing the induction variable to the end of the while loop.